# How do I extract string representation of column name from a pyspark.sql.Column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark `Column` object.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import Column

my_col: Column = col('foo')
```

How do then I extract the string `'foo'` from the `my_col` object?

The best I could come up with is using `repr` but that feels very awkward:

```py
col_name: str = repr(my_col)[8:-2]
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, seems like it's possible to do:

```
col_name = my_col._jc.toString()
```